# Remove all uppercase letters in a string except the first letter using perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a word list imported into an array. Many of the words start with a capital letter. So many of the words may start with an uppercase letter, this is okay. I want to delete all occurrences of uppercase letters unless it's the first letter of the word.

```
use strict;

my $filter_file = "filter.txt";
my $filtered_file = "filtered.txt";
my $file_data= "";


#### Place file contents into an array ####
open (RESULTS, $filter_file) or die "Unable to open file: $filter_file\n$!";
my @file_data;
@file_data = <RESULTS>;
close(RESULTS);

#### Search the array ####
for(@file_data) {
# attempting different regular expression's 
   s/[[:lower:]]\K[[:upper:]].*//;
   s/([[:lower:]])[[:upper:]].*/$1/;
    }

#### Save filtered data to file ###
open (FILE, ">> $filtered_file") || die "Unable to open file: $filtered_file\n$!";
print FILE @file_data;
close($filtered_file);
```

Comment: Provide example of input and expected output.

Comment: You can use the non-word-boundary anchor `\B`. Something like `s/\B[A-Z]+//g`

Comment: What's your definition of a word?

Comment: You sure you want to *delete* upper case letters, or just lower case them?  Does "CamelCase" come out as "Camelcase" or "Camelase"... some sort of enzyme for dissolving camels... eww.

Comment: By word, I mean string. Each string is generally an english word. However, some of the words/strings have random uppercase letters on the end. I want to remove the uppercase letters attached to the end of the string. The input has a string/word on a separate line. An example would be "WordSRR". I would want the output to be "Word".

Comment: I need to delete uppercase letters trailing the end of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your definition of a word? If you're just looking at letters, you almost had it. You want uppercase following any letter, not just lowercase letters.

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "ABcDe"; s/\pL\K\p{Lu}+//g; say'
Ace
```

Comment: An example of the input: WordS MorewordsRRR. Each on a separate line. I  would want output similar to: Word Morewords. Each on a separate line.

Comment: @Andrew Taylor, Sorry, I fail to see the point of your last comment.

Comment: This is an example of the input and expected output: http://pastebin.com/GPfsJff3

Comment: I underdstood what you said; I just don't know why you're telling me such things. What's your point?

Comment: I was just trying to better clarify the situation. And I was asked to 'define a word'. Thanks for your help.